# Reusing joins between different parts of a query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following tables:

```
CREATE TABLE sequence (
  id serial PRIMARY KEY
  -- ...other sequence data
)

CREATE TABLE sound (
  id serial PRIMARY KEY
  -- ...other sound data
)

CREATE TABLE layer (
  id serial PRIMARY KEY,
  index smallint NOT NULL,
  sequence integer NOT NULL REFERENCES sequence (id)
)

CREATE TABLE layerSound (
  id serial PRIMARY KEY,
  index smallint NOT NULL,
  layer integer NOT NULL REFERENCES layer (id),
  sound integer NOT NULL REFERENCES sound (id)
)
```

So I have sequences. Each sequence has many layers. Each layer
has many layerSounds. Each layerSound has one sound attached to it.

I want to write a query (returning JSON) that can select a certain sequence
by its ID, and then also join:

- an array of layers used by this sequence
- an aggregated array of layerSounds, grouped by layer
- an array of unique sounds used by this sequence (across all layerSounds)

For example:

```
{
  sequence: 3,
  layers: [1, 2],
  layerSounds: [
    { layer: 1, sounds: [1, 2] },
    { layer: 2, sounds: [2, 3] }
  ],
  sounds: [
    { id: 1, foo: "bar" },
    { id: 2, foo: "baz" },
    { id: 3, foo: "blah" }
  ]
}
```

So the aim is to only write the distinct sound data out in full once, and then the layerSounds.sounds
array just has the sound IDs. So the sound data is not duplicated.

My approach so far is to SELECT the sequence, then aggregate the other tables separately. I group each by sequence ID and then join once against the outer query.

While this works, I notice I'm having to repeat joins in each JOIN query in order to always group by sequenceId.

So to group layerSounds by sequenceId, I join layer to layerSound to sound. I then do the exact same join again to calculate all sounds used by this sequence. I've included the query below.

My question is, is there a way to improve this query? Is there something wrong with this approach? Or is re-using joins like this normal?

Thanks for your time.

Query:

```
SELECT
  sequence.id,
  layers.ids AS layers,
  layerSounds.ids AS layerSounds,
  sounds.ids AS sounds
FROM sequence
JOIN (
  SELECT
    sequence,
    json_agg(id) AS ids
  FROM layer
  GROUP BY sequence
) layers ON layers.sequence = sequence.id
JOIN (
  SELECT
    sequence,
    json_agg(layerSounds) AS ids
  FROM layer
  JOIN (
    SELECT
      layerSound.layer,
      json_agg(sound.id) AS ids
    FROM layerSound
    JOIN sound
    ON sound.id = layerSound.sound
    GROUP BY layerSound.layer
  ) layerSounds ON layerSounds.layer = layer.id
  GROUP BY sequence
) layerSounds ON layerSounds.sequence = sequence.id
JOIN (
  SELECT
    sequence,
    json_agg(DISTINCT sound.id) AS ids
  FROM layer
  JOIN layerSound
    ON layerSound.layer = layer.id
  JOIN sound
    ON sound.id = layerSound.sound
  GROUP BY sequence
) sounds ON sounds.sequence = sequence.id
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can definitely simplify the query.  I think this is one simplification:

```
SELECT s.id, l.ids AS layers, ls.ids AS layerSounds,
       so.ids AS sounds
FROM sequence s JOIN
     (SELECT l.sequence, json_agg(l.id) AS ids,
             json_agg(ls)
      FROM layer l JOIN
           (SELECT ls.layer, json_agg(ls.sound) AS ids
            FROM layerSound ls 
            GROUP BY ls.layer
           ) ls
           ON ls.layer = l.id
      GROUP BY l.sequence
     ) l
     ON l.sequence = s.id JOIN
     (SELECT l.sequence,
             json_agg(DISTINCT ls.sound) AS ids
      FROM layer l JOIN
           layerSound ls
           ON ls.layer = l.id
      GROUP BY l.sequence
     ) so
     ON so.sequence = s.id;
```

A key observation is that you don't need to join to `sounds`, because the information is in `layerSound`.

The first subquery combines the first two subqueries in your version.  In Postgres, there might be a way to combine the layer sound JSON arrays into a single array (perhaps by using Postgres arrays as an intermediary).  But this does the last list as a separate subquery.

Comment: Thanks, that helped a lot. I'm going to use array_agg for ls.sound and transform to JSON elsewhere - then I can use unnest on the array to get the distinct sound IDs across all layers.